# Why aren't nodes b and c considered the same node?

Tags: current, nodal-analysis

I am new to circuits and trying to practice nodal analysis. Why are nodes b and c considered different nodes?

[image]

Comment: Who claims they are not the same node?

Comment: They are same node. Well, you *can* consider them as different nodes, if it is simplifying your analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, they are the same node.  However, for the purposes of nodal analysis you can *treat* them as two separate nodes.  It makes for more bookkeeping when you do the math, but it doesn't change any results.

I can't say what the author was thinking, but if I were teaching basic circuit analysis, I'd do that so that I could talk about \$i_2\$ and \$i_3\$ separately.

Answer (score 1):

From a current perspective they are different nodes. From a voltage perspective they are the same node.

I would label them as \$b_1\$ and \$b_2\$. The letter indicates a region of same voltage (voltage node). The numerical subscript enumerates the current nodes.

Comment: It makes sense to separate  them as "current nodes" only if we are interested in the current between them. Otherwise they can be collapsed into one adhering KCL.

Answer (score 0):

A node is a point where two or more circuit elements' terminals are connected together. Here b and c are connected to the same point. You can consider it as a single node.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They are the same node. To analyze them as separate nodes, you can add a "test resistance" between *b* and *c*, separating them. Then, take the results in the limit as the test resistance goes to 0.

Comment: I just use a voltage source with 0 V.